# How to show data to front end?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to learning how to implement open weather API. I don't fully know how to show data to razor view. So if I wanted to show temp how would I do it. I don't want to use viewbag to show data.

I am using a tuple in razor view to implement 2 models. The openweatherModel which takes zipcode as input. The other is RootObject which is a class inside Json.cs which holds json information like temp, coord, description etc.

Api

```
public class ApiController 
    {
        public async Task<Json.RootObject> GetResult(int zipCode)
        {
            const string apiKey = "";
            var client = new HttpClient();


            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" +
                                                 zipCode + ",us&APPID=" + apiKey);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json.RootObject>(responseBody);
        }
```

Home

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Main()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Main(int zipCode)
        {
             var controller = new ApiController();

            var rootObject = await controller.GetResult(zipCode);

           var tuple = new Tuple<OpenWeatherMap, RootObject>(new OpenWeatherMap(), new RootObject());

            return View(tuple);
        }
```

Razor

```
@model  Tuple<Weather.Models.OpenWeatherMap, Weather.HelperClasses.Json.RootObject>
 <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Main", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "container" }))
        {


            @Html.TextBoxFor(tuple =>tuple.Item1.zipCode, new {@Name = "zipCode", @class = "inputs", required = "Required", placeholder = "Enter ZipCode" })

            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />

            foreach (var items in Model.Item2.weather)
            {
                <h1>@items.description</h1>
            }
        }
    </div>
```

RootObject

```
 public class RootObject
        {
            public Coord coord { get; set; }
            public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
            public string @base { get; set; }
            public Main main { get; set; }
            public int visibility { get; set; }
            public Wind wind { get; set; }
            public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
            public int dt { get; set; }
            public Sys sys { get; set; }
            public int timezone { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int cod { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: I tried using a foreach(var items in Model.item2.weather) but I keep getting a object not set to null reference. I added few more details

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Your `Tuple` is in a `POST` action (_**after**_ your `form` is submitted). Ergo your `view`, which has the `form` that has _yet to be submitted_ has no such `Tuple` to work with (`null`) _yet_. Create your model and pass it to the view that has the `form`.